# Multiple line plots in one graph from long format

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, long-format-data

I have 100 individuals with each 3 points of a variable (after 0,6, and 12 months). I sorted them by variable in ascending order at Time = 0 and used the vector "c" for this.

```
    PatID pDC_of_lymphocytes_percentage Time c
2   001-502                         0.000    0 1
3   001-502                         0.051    6 1
1   001-502                         0.880   12 1
19  001-518                         0.000    0 2
20  001-518                         0.250    6 2
21  001-518                         0.210   12 2
87  021-503                         0.000    0 3
86  021-503                         0.350    6 3
85  021-503                         1.510   12 3
104 025-501                         0.000    0 4
103 025-501                         0.030    6 4
105 025-501                         0.000   12 4
```

Now I try to plot line plots for each of them, but the line plots should be:

- in the order from lowest to highest starting value
- always multiple lines in one graph (e.g. 10 lines)

I have tried with the pull function, but it only plots me one line in each graph, since only 1 ID is pulled at a time.

```
pdf(paste("pDCoflymphocytespercentage.pdf",sep = ""), width = 15)
l_ply(pDC.frame.plot %>% distinct(PatID) %>% pull(), function(patID) {
  patDF <- pDC.frame.plot %>% filter(PatID == patID)
  patDF$Time <- as.numeric(patDF$Time)
  
  print(
    ggplot(patDF, aes(x=Time)) +  
      
      geom_line(aes(y=pDC_of_lymphocytes_percentage, linetype="solid", group=1),colour = "steelblue",size=2,name="") +
      scale_linetype(name="") +
      

      )
  )
  
}, .progress = "text")
dev.off()
```

any solution how I can get multiple line plots in one graph, with one for each PatID at Time 0,6,12?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
library(ggplot2)
df<- tibble::tribble(
  ~PatID, ~pDC_of_lymphocytes_percentage, ~Time,
  "001-502", 0.000, 0,
  "001-502", 0.051, 6,
  "001-502", 0.880, 12,
  "001-518", 0.000, 0,
  "001-518", 0.250, 6,
  "001-518", 0.210, 12,
  "021-503", 0.000, 0,
  "021-503", 0.350, 6,
  "021-503", 1.510, 12,
  "025-501", 0.000, 0,
  "025-501", 0.030, 6,
  "025-501", 0.000, 12
)

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = pDC_of_lymphocytes_percentage)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~PatID)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, already really nice. But can you also plot multiple lines in one coordinate system?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But how do you want to identify each line (PatID) then? That's not clear in your original question ;)

Comment: for example have different colors, or dont identify them at all. Your code works even better then what I imagined though, thanks a lot!